# Test Automation using Node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing, automated-tests

My client has a new system in development using node.js.

I need to write automation scripts for the system and my client has recommended me to go with node.js this time so the developers can also take part in creation of Automation scripts.

I need recommendation for Test Automation frameworks that I could use. I have experience working with Selenium WebDriver using Java.

Any guidance and direction would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonably logic option in your case would be to try [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/), as it is an implementation of the Selenium 2.0 bindings for NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

You might try out [NightwachJs](http://nightwatchjs.org/).  I did some experimenting with it recently and it seemed a reasonable node.js compatible automation framework.

Comment: Thanks @Breaks Software

Answer (score 0):

There are abundant of node.js packages you can use for test automation, which covers almost all types of test automation, for example,

- For API testing,  you can use "got", "request", "axios" etc.
- For Web UI testing,  you can use "[selenium-webdriver](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/)",
  [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/), puppeteer, etc.
- For mobile or Windows UI testing, you can use [appium](http://appium.io/)

All these packages can be found on npm registry:
[www.npmjs.org](http://www.npmjs.org)

If you want to use natural language to define your test case and associate them with the automation code, you can use the BDD tool [cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js)

BTW, one free tool that can be used to author all above types of test automation is [CukeTest](http://cuketest.com), which is free to download and use.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.protractortest.org](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) is also popular if you have an angular application

Answer (score 0):

We currently use Puppeteer in the system to test our UI functions. We use a tool called Last-hit.https://github.com/last-hit-aab/last-hit
This tool only needs recording and playback. It is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Implement nightwatch.js
advantages

1. lightweight library
2. easy to implement in Node.js
3. can be integration to CI /CD tools
4. also available docker images

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/), [NightwatchJS](https://nightwatchjs.org/) or [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to automate non Angular applications. Use [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) for Angular applications.

There are few testing framework such as [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [CucumberJS](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/javascript/)